# Elsewhere in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: anglais, usage, mathématiques

> In this notes we study the numerical solution. Elsewhere, we have studied the analytical one.
>
> Dans ces notes, nous étudions la solution numérique. Ailleurs, nous avons présenté la solution analytique.

Can we use ailleurs for conveying elsewhere in this context ?

Comment: Oui! Note qu'ici, je le préférerais reporté en fin de phrase : *...analytique ailleurs.*

Comment: Note que si, comme on peut s'y attendre vu le contexte, **tu** as vu avec tes étudiants la solution analytique **précédemment**, tu peux aussi utiliser : *auparavant* (*Nous avions présenté la sol anal auparavant.*)

Comment: Allez : ***Par ailleurs*** et on n'en parle plus! ;-)

Comment: There seem to be some problems with the English text. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Ailleurs" (ou plutôt *Par ailleurs* proposé par @aCOSwt dans un commentaire) me parait trop vague pour un document scientifique.

En général, selon le contexte, on utilise plutôt :

- Dans un autre document, dans d'autres notes, dans une autre section, un autre chapitre

Ou mieux:

- Dans tel document, dans telles notes (en citant une référence si besoin)
- Ci-dessus, auparavant, précédemment
- En annexe
- Dans telle section, ou tel chapitre

Le point essentiel est que le lecteur doit pouvoir retrouver l'information rapidement.

Ceci dit, je suis très surpris de voir apparaitre *elsewhere*, qui est vague également. Je ne me rappelle pas avoir lu ce mot dans un document scientifique, pour indiquer un autre document, ou une autre partie du même document.

Comment: OT peut-etre, mais je suis d'accord que *elsewhere* tout seul semble trop vague ici. Cependant, des fois on le voit suivi par les precisions en parenthese/incise, e.g. "considered elsewhere (supra/infra note 244, at 148)."

Comment: @PapaPoule Effectivement, dans ce cas ça devient très précis. Une possibilité est *nous avons présenté la solution analytique par ailleurs (note xx)*. Je préfère par exemple *La solution analytique a déjà présentée (note xx)*. Nous étudions ici ...*. Mais c'est une question de goût. Que signifie *OT* ?

Comment: OT= Off topic (hors sujet?). Je voulais dire par ca que mon commentaire etait [peut-etre] hors sujet (pas votre reponse!) car il s'agissait de l'usage de *elsewhere*, un mot anglais.

Comment: Oui! C'est vrai de dire que c'est vague. Et c'est vrai que les scientifiques ont coutume de citer précisément. Maintenant... il existe des cas où... oui! Même scientifique... le vague n'a aucune importance. L'OP précise qu'il s'agit de notes! Et, très probablement d'un autre cours donné par le même OP... dans ce cas... C'est de moi, c'est je sais plus où... et puis en plus... c'est pas grave que cela soit ici ou ailleurs... => c'est ailleurs.

Comment: @aCOSwt Aïe. J'espère que je n'ai pas vexé l'OP. Je n'avais pas compris qu'il est l'auteur du texte en anglais... En tant que scientifique (enfin j'essaie) je suis bien placé pour savoir que la rigueur est un but plutôt qu'un résultat toujours atteint. Et des notes de cours ne sont pas un article effectivement.

Comment: En plus, on réalise que c'est dit en transition. D'un cours à un autre. D'un cours sur lequel on ne reviendra pas. (Et que... il vaut même peut-être pour l'heure oublier...) Il est ailleurs et il y reste.

Comment: @aCOSwt Là c'est toi qui risques de le vexer ! :)

Comment: Je disais *qu'il vaut peut-être mieux l'oublier* au sens où... quand on fait de la résolution numérique... il vaut mieux oublier les réflexes acquis dans le cadre de la résolution analytique.

Answer (score 2):

« Ailleurs » is  something of a nondescript term in this context, not quite proper. It seems to me it is better to try to be more specific; since the matter referred to has been studied in a recent past, something such as "**Récemment,**", "**Il n'y a pas longtemps,**" would be preferable.

If that former study was also found in some notes, another possibility is "**Dans des notes antérieures,**".

Comment: I agree with "antérieurement" and variants. Also consider "Précédemment"